# react-native app error Unknown option: .name (?)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, vbcodeprovider

I recently installed files that caused a previous error these two files were not found so I installed them

"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
"react-native-dotenv": "^2.4.3",

Now I get this error: Any feedback to repair and be able to view my app is appreciated :)

error: App.js: [BABEL] C:\xampp\vibenote-texting\App.js: Unknown option: .name. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.

Answer (score 4):

react-native-dotenv maintainer here:

This is a common problem that indicates you need to move `react-native-dotenv` from the `presets` to the `plugins` section in the `babel.config.js` file.